# Rails 4 nested forms link_to edit not working in loop

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, crud, nested-forms, link-to

I have a nested routes/models/forms in rails. On my index page I am listing the todo_lists with the todo_items underneath. I want to be able to click on my todo list title and then it takes me to the edit page. I research polymorphic routes and nested routes.

**UPDATE**

This was my fix to stop it from creating the dummy todo list.

```
<%  @current_todo_lists.each do |list| %>
    <% if list.id %>
        <div class="panel">
            <p><strong><%= link_to list.title ,edit_todo_list_path(list)%></strong></p>
            <% list.todo_items.each do |todo_item| %>
                <p><%= todo_item.description %></p>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

[github link](https://github.com/tjperry07/blocitoff)

[Link_to rails nested form edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044042/link-to-rails-nested-form-edit)

[polymorphic_path not generating correct path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343535/polymorphic-path-not-generating-correct-path)
I have done a lot quite a bit of research looking to cocoon, rails guides on polymorphic routes and several other stackoverflow links.

I have not been successful in making any of these work.

Here is the index page where all my todo_lists with todo_items are listed. It goes through a loop to list each todo list with the corresponding items created with it

**Update:**

I already tried `<%= link_to list.title, edit_todo_list_path(list) %>`and `<%= link_to list.title, edit_todo_list_path(@list) %>`. 
The error message I get is :

`ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /todo_lists
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"todo_lists", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]` 
This same configuration with @todo_list gives the same error. 
Basically it can't find the Todo List with an id.

In the console does give me a result. So I am missing something.

```
>> t = TodoList.find(1)
=> #<TodoList id: 1, title: "First todo List with a modal", created_at: "2014-09-09 23:02:27", updated_at: "2014-09-09 23:02:27", user_id: 1>
>>
```

**Update 2:** This is where the error is happening in my todo list controller. It can't find without id.

```
def set_todo_list
@todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:id])
end


<% @todo_lists.each do |list| %> 
    <p><strong><%= link_to list.title, edit_polymorphic_path(@todo_list) %></strong></p>
    <% list.todo_items.each do |todo_item| %>
        <p><%= todo_item.description %></p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So far `<p><strong><%= link_to list.title, edit_polymorphic_path(@todo_list) %` parameters have been @todo_list(s), @ todo_lists(s), todo_items and so on.

Models:

```
class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :todo_items, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :todo_items, allow_destroy: true
    validates_presence_of :title
end

class TodoItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :todo_list
end
```

Controllers:

```
Class TodoListsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter except: [:index]
  before_action :set_todo_list, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /todo_lists
  # GET /todo_lists.json
  def index
    #@todo_lists = TodoList.all
    #find current user todo lists/items
    @todo_lists = current_user.todo_lists
    @todo_items = current_user.todo_items
    #create a new user todo list
    @todo_list = current_user.todo_lists.new
    # builder for todo list _form
    3.times{ @todo_list.todo_items.build }
  end

  # GET /todo_lists/1
  # GET /todo_lists/1.json
  def show
  end

  # # GET /todo_lists/new
  def new
    @todo_list = current_user.todo_lists.new
    3.times{ @todo_list.todo_items.build }
  end

  # GET /todo_lists/1/edit
  def edit
    #@todo_list = TodoList.find(todo_list_params)
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /todo_lists
  # POST /todo_lists.json
  def create
    #@todo_list = TodoList.new(todo_list_params)
    @todo_list = current_user.todo_lists.new(todo_list_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo list was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo_list }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /todo_lists/1
  # PATCH/PUT /todo_lists/1.json
  def update
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_list.update(todo_list_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo list was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @todo_list }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /todo_lists/1
  # DELETE /todo_lists/1.json
  def destroy
    #@todo_list.TodoList.find(params[:id])
    @todo_list.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to todo_lists_url, notice: 'Todo list was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def owns_todolist
      if current_user != TodoList.find(params[:id]).user
        redirect_to todo_lists_path, error: "You can't do that!"
      end
    end
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_todo_list
      @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def todo_list_params
      params.require(:todo_list).permit(:title, todo_items_attributes: [:description, :_destroy])
    end
end



class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_todo_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_todo_list

  # GET /todo_items
  # GET /todo_items.json
  def index
    @todo_items = TodoItem.all
  end

  # GET /todo_items/1
  # GET /todo_items/1.json
  def show
    @todo_item = TodoItem.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /todo_items/new
  def new
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.build
  end

  # GET /todo_items/1/edit
  def edit
    @todo_item = TodoItem.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /todo_items
  # POST /todo_items.json
  def create
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.build(todo_item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@todo_list,@todo_item], notice: 'Todo item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @todo_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /todo_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /todo_items/1.json
  def update
    @todo_item = TodoItem.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_item.update(todo_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_item, notice: 'Todo item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @todo_item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @todo_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /todo_items/1
  # DELETE /todo_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @todo_item = TodoItem.find(params[:id])
    @todo_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to todo_list_todo_items_url, notice: 'Todo item was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_todo_item
      @todo_item = TodoItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_todo_list
      @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def todo_item_params
      params.require(:todo_item).permit(:description, :text, :todo_list_id)
    end
end
```

and finally the form. Right now it allows for adding a todo_list and a few todo_items just as practice. I plan on using some Ajax to allow for dynamic creation later on. And having a different form for editing.

```
<%= form_for(@todo_list) do |f| %>
  <% if @todo_list.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@todo_list.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this todo_list from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @todo_list.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.fields_for :todo_items do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.label :description, "Items" %>
      <%= builder.text_field :description %>
      <%= builder.check_box '_destroy' %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `edit_polymorphic_path`? Neither TodoList or TodoItem is polymorphic , just use `edit_todo_list_path(list)`.

Comment: I tried that.First thing I did. I edited my question above with the error I get.

Comment: edit_todo_list_path(id: @list.id)

Comment: `edit_todo_list_path(list)` should work. (@list isn't a variable here). If it isn't working, is the error message the same? (Is the ID still nil? If it's still a routing error, but the ID isn't nil, you may need to add an edit path to your routes.rb file). Also, polymorphism is for data relationships unlike the one you have here. It doesn't seem like the right tool for the job.

Comment: To answer your question: ```ActionController::UrlGenerationError in TodoLists#index``` No it doesn't work. ```No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"todo_lists", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue's actually a little trickier, because `edit_todo_list_path(list)` seems to throw the same error.

What's going on is that the `@todo_lists` variable (first an array of persisted lists) is altered when you run `@todo_list = current_user.todo_lists.new`. That command actually adds a new (unpersisted) list to the end of the `@todo_lists` array (seems like buggy behavior to me, but it's happened to me before), so that when your view is looping through them, the last one has no id, and a path cannot be created for it.

The solution is (I think) to make that variable after you've used the `@todo_lists` variable.

Take `@todo_list` out of the controller, and where you use it in the view, instead do `current_user.todo_lists.build`. That should instantiate a new list *without* changing the `@todo_lists` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create a link to a resource that has not been persisted yet:

```
#create a new user todo list
@todo_list = current_user.todo_lists.new
```

Since you never call `@todo_list.save` the record does not have a ID and cannot be routed to.

I think what you are trying to do is:

```
<% @todo_lists.each do |list| %> 
  <p><strong><%= link_to list.title, edit_polymorphic_path(id: list.to_param) #not @todo_list! %></strong></p>
  <% list.todo_items.each do |todo_item| %>
    <p><%= todo_item.description %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And I would seriously consider renaming `@todo_list` -> `@new_todo_list` since it´s pretty confusing as is.

---

### Update

"I can even click a button to open a modal which will create a new todo list all from the same page."

What you should do then is have the user create a new a resource by posting the form with an AJAX POST request to `/todo_list` and then update the page with the new list (and an edit link).

What you are doing now is creating a new todo_list which only exists in the servers memory before rails finishes processing the request.

Comment: Let me clarify. The code above will list out each todo list with the todo items. I can even click a button to open a modal which will create a new todo list all from the same page. Once the list is created. I am trying to create an edit link using the title. ```edit_polymorphic_path(id: list.to_param)``` Is not working. I added another edit above.

Comment: If you wanted to explicitly set the id, you should do `path(id: list.id)`. I agree that the path should be `edit_todo_path`, and the ID really should be extracted automatically. I think the issue was, as papirtiger was saying, that you were passing the wrong (non-persisted -- ie IDless) object to the path helper.

Comment: Thanks for help everyone. Thanks to @papirtiger for the suggestion to rename my variables. That has led to quite a bit of simplification and me cleaning up my code.